# Can a variable be declared inside xsl:if in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to declare a variable inside an `xsl:if`, but I don't know if this is possible in XSLT.

This is what I have so far:

```
<xsl:if test="mstns:OutlineLevel = 1">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="0" /> 
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="mstns:OutlineLevel = 2">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$parent" /> 
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

What I want is:

```
<xsl:if test="mstns:OutlineLevel = 1">
    <xsl:variable name="parent" >
        <set the value of the variable to mstns:ID>
    </xsl:variable>
</xsl:if>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's possible to declare a variable within `xsl:if` but there's not much you can do with it: its scope is limited to the scope of its parent instruction. It would be better to ask about what are you actually hoping to accomplish here, instead of focusing on this or other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could maybe help you.

```html
<xsl:variable name="parent">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="mstns:OutlineLevel = 1">
      <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="mstns:OutlineLevel = 2">
      <xsl:text>2</xsl:text>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: That really helped with one tag in xslt!! Thanks!! Now appeared another question about parent and child tasks, like the ones in the microsoft project. Do you know any way to that relationship in a tag?? lets say for example, <data> <task> <subtask> when mstns:OutlineNumber &gt; 1 this is a child with the selected id from the task id.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a variable can be declared inside an `xsl:if` in XSLT:

```
<xsl:if test="  TEST XPATH EXPRESSION  ">

  <!-- variable declaration alternatives -->

  <xsl:variable name="var" select="  XPATH EXPRESSION  "/>

  <!-- or -->

  <xsl:variable name="var">
    <!-- variable binding element -->
  </xsl:variable>

  <!-- or -->

  <xsl:variable name="var"/>
  <!-- ($var is an empty string in this case) -->


  <!-- First use of $var-->
  <!-- Second use of $var-->
  <!-- ... -->

</xsl:if>
```